# Reach native Hook pass and get params

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

**Pass and get parameters using react-native Hook**

I need to pass data to the next page through the navigation and get passed parameters using the `useEffect()` method.

```
// Pass parameter in render component  useEffect()
    
            <TouchableOpacity
              
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate("ProductsCategory", {
                  category: item.name,
                  id: "1212",
                });
              }}
            >
             <Text>Click here</Text>
           
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ));
        }
      }



// Get parameter using  useEffect()

useEffect(() => {
    _get_sub_categories();
    
  }, []);
```

Comment: Do you need them on the same component? So when you navigate the effect should happen? Or do you just need to read the value on the component you are navigating to? If the later is the case, you can use useRoute hook from react navigation,

Comment: Edit your question, so it's clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: why do you want to get them through use effect they are available right away and it doesn't look like it will change, just get the param when you need it or use ueseState